# How to push the same edit to different branches in git?

Tags: git, git-workflow

I have a Git repository which has a master branch. Now I want to create different branches which have the same changes in every branch (for example the database). So I can have these files in **master**:

- a.java
- b.java
- database-1.xml

and two branches, called **branch-1** and **branch-2**, with these files:

- a.java
- b.java
- database-branch-1.xml

and

- a.java
- b.java
- database-branch-2.xml

Now, let that I find a bug in `a.java`, obviously I would like to fix it and commit the same change in every branch. How can I achieve my goal?

**Note**: The database files must remain different and the other files will be always the same.

Comment: You want to commit the change to every branch, or you want the change to be in every branch.  Also, are you the only one working on these branches or are other people as well?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I want to commit the change to every branch.

Comment: If *branch-1* and *branch-2* are created off of *master*, could you just commit to *master* and merge or rebase the changes into the other branches?

Comment: Why are you branching off without any plan to merge back to master later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

merge. But it's best to change the file a.java at the common starting point where there is only database-1.xml otherwise it will get clobbered.

Cherry pick is the other way. But managing branches that way becomes unmanagable quickly.

This brings up the point about deploy config. You should not branch just because your config is changing based on where you're deploying. Make database.xml not work at all. Rely on deployment scripts or smudge/clean scripts to adjust the config based on where you're deploying - even locally.

This means the config should have the structure you need but be adjusted only in the areas it needs to be - usually just a connection string.

Think of what happens when you need to adjust something in the database file that has to go across all branches.

Comment: Surely it would be nice to branch after but my problem arises from the fact that it can arise after i make the branches.

Comment: You can checkout the common point, make the change on a branch that you start there and then merge that into each of your main branches. This would allow you to not impact the db files.

Comment: This seems good but have I to merge each branch individually?

Comment: This is the problem. You shouldn't have to. You are working around the problem of config. It seems you have the branches only for the sake of the database file. That is not a good enough reason to make a branch dedicated to a deploy site.

Comment: An edit to the database will never go across in all the branches.

Comment: there is no need to version this. You would want to just have it as a config step and simplify your history.

Comment: Your last comment seems interesting. Could you put me in the right way?

Comment: checkout simple scripts that use `sed` to replace a portion of the config file. You can embed that in a smudge/clean script so it's done automatically for you every time you checkout on a deploy site.

Answer (score 2):

The possible solution depends on your workflow.

**Option 1: Rewriting the history**
If you do **not push** the branches to a remote repository you could commit the bugfix on the *master* branch since this is the common starting point of file `a.java`. Right after, you can rebase each branch to include this change.

**Option 1a: Rewriting the history of topic branches only**
Another workflow is based on conventions. You can have topic branches that are pushed to the server as you push the *master* branch. The convention is, that those topic branches are **never merged into the master** and **rewriting the history is allowed**. A topic branch can be private to one developer or shared among others. For the latter scenario the group has to coordinate before and after a rebase happens. When the topic branch work is done the branch gets rebased against the *master* and a fast-forward branch can be applied easily.

**Option 2: Cherry pick**
If you push the branches to a remote repository it is not recommened to rewrite the history. In short, the only option you have is to commit a bugfix on top of each branch. To avoid do the same job twice, `git cherry-pick` is the recommended command (as already told by Adam and Albert).

**Option 3: Merge master back into each topic branch**
This is the git part of Adam's answer. You can commit the bugfix on the *master* branch, which is the common starting point of the affected file. Then, you can merge the *master* back into the topic branches. That is in effect the same as updating the topic branch with all changes that have happened on the *master* branch in the meantime. This disadvantage is that you cannot choose the bugfix alone. This is what `git cherry-pick` allows (see Option 2).

**Note:**
If you do **not** plan to **merge** the two branches, you could actually use the same `database-1.xml` file for the specific configuration on each branch.

**Project setup**
Besides the different ways to work with git I totally agree with Adam's answer in the fact that you should definitely rethink your project setup and create a configuration file that allows you to specify different environments. A good example is the database configuration file of a RubyOnRails project as you might know.

```
// Rails project: config/database.yml

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: In this scenario I push the branches to a remote repository so I think the first solution is not applicable.

Comment: cherry-pick is not the recommended way. A topic branch from the original branch point is recommended. Cherry-picking can make for a nasty history.

Comment: Agreed. So, what is your problem using `git cherry-pick`? It sounds as if you are afraid of using the command?

Comment: I don't agree: if you simply bugfix a small portion the history will not be destroyed.

Comment: not afraid of the command at all. And it has it's place. It does not replace proper branch management.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git-cherry-pick` to apply specific commits: [git-cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)